# Saving translated slug of django modeltranslation not working

Tags: python, django, translation, slug

I've been breaking my head over this for a day now.

I use django-modeltranslation to translate blog-like posts. All works fine, except I also try to automatically translate the slugs from the title, based off of this article: https://raphaelbeck.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/how-to-translate-slug-with-django-modeltranslation/

Only the translated slug is not translated saved to the database.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'help.category',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='categories')
    title = models.CharField(_('Titel'),max_length=255)
    description = RichTextField(_('Omschrijving'))
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), populate_from='title', overwrite=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Item") 
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Items")

        #automatically creating slugs for translations
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for lang_code, lang_verbose in settings.LANGUAGES:
            if hasattr(self, 'slug_%s' % lang_code) and hasattr(self, 'title_%s' % lang_code):
                setattr(self, 'slug_%s' % lang_code, slugify(getattr(self, 'title_%s' % lang_code, u"")))
            print(self.slug_nl)
            print(self.slug_en)

        print(self.slug_nl)
        print(self.slug_en)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

I added some print funtions to see what actually happens. The console logs are as expected:

dutch-slug

None

dutch-slug

english-slug

dutch-slug

english-slug

-> slug_en is translated correctly based on the title in the console, but in the database the dutch slugs are saved.

Thanks in advance! Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your model actually have fields 'slug_nl'? ie. did you register `slug` in *translations.py*?

Comment: Yes on both of the questions. In the database they are all stored, slug_nl, slug and slug_en. All of them have the dutch version of the slug.

Comment: Have you tried setting `AUTOSLUG_MODELTRANSLATION_ENABLE` to `True` in your settings? That should do what you want without having to code anything. Not sure why your code isn't working but it might be related to Autoslug now supporting django-modeltranslation.

Comment: AUTOSLUG_MODELTRANSLATION_ENABLE seems to be a django-autoslug feature. I don't use this package (also because I'm moving project to django 2 with which it seems to be incompatible). Am I right?

Comment: What’s `AutoSlugField` then? Django doesn’t have that.

Comment: from django_extensions

Comment: Looking at the source of AutoSlugField from Django-autoslug, the modeltranslation stuff is done post_save (in a signal) so *after* the model was saved. It does mean the model is saved twice but probably it’s the only way as I think model translation is otherwise interfering with autoslug.

Comment: Yeah, I think you mean line 302 from https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug/blob/223771076e63c1b50f75fb2a576f2ea4c6bad514/autoslug/fields.py right? So how would I implement this in my code?

Comment: Move your code to a `post_save` signal handler. Instead of setting the attribute with `setattr`, you create a dictionary (like they do in line 353) and pass it at the end to `update()` on a queryset so that `save()` isn't called recursively.

Comment: Is your `save` correct?  The tutorial you're following uses `super(<ClassName>, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: @Rachel that's basic python, not needed in python3.

Comment: @dirkgroten  True.  I didn't see him specify which python he is using.

Comment: @Rachel I'm using python3, I actually removed it

Comment: Ok.  It was just a thought.

Comment: I know, Thanks!
@dirkgroten Thanks, that was the solution! I will post an update later when I have the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-model-translation and `AutoSlugField` perform what they need to do during the `save()` method, so what you do prior to saving is overwritten later.

There's no other way than to add the translations post-save, even if that means saving the model twice. Also you can't call `save()` in post_save otherwise you create an endless recursion. Use `update()` on the queryset. Write a `post_save` signal handler:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Item)
def add_slug_translations(instance, **kwargs):
    attrs = {}
    for lang_code, lang_verbose in settings.LANGUAGES:
        if hasattr(self, 'slug_%s' % lang_code) and hasattr(self, 'title_%s' % lang_code) and getattr(self, 'title_%s' % lang_code):
            attrs.update({'slug_%s' % lang_code: slugify(getattr(self, 'title_%s' % lang_code, u"")})
    if attrs:
        Item.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(**attrs)
```